# rhel6 repsitories gives broken dependencies

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, rhel6

i tried several repositories for rhel 6 like epel,freshrpms,etc and all the repositories give broken dependency while installing pakages(eg:vlc,exaile).From where i get a repository without broken dependency.i need codec,vlc player,qt-creator,eclipse.

please suggest a good repo.

Is rhel6 repo suitable for centos6 ?

Comment: show your broken dependency output and the `yum repolist`?

Comment: i will send it soon.                                           while installing vlc it could not find some packages from the mirror.

Comment: i got this problem while installing vlc.........Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge) Requires: libml.so.2.0 Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge) Requires: libcvaux.so.2.0 Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge) Requires: libdvdread.so.4 Error: Package: dirac-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge) etc...

Comment: Append the output of `rpm -qa | grep vlc` and `yum repolist` to the original post to keep formating.

Comment: [root@localhost ak]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
repo id                repo name                                       status
rpmforge               RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag               4,136
repolist: 4,136
[root@localhost ak]#

Comment: Are you sure you are running CentOS?

Comment: the above result from rhel6.

Comment: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-register.html

Comment: did you mean,the registration will solve all problems?

Answer (score 1):

When I was initially setting up my CentOS boxes I ran into a lot of similar problems.

RHEL and CentOS repos may be used interchangeably. With a degree of care even RHEL 5 repos may be used. When it comes to using these repos you need to use only a single external repository - either RPMForge, EPEL, etc. Mixing repositories creates a major problem. Also be sure to use the yum-priorties plugin.

When it comes to the packages listed with broken dependencies they can generally be removed and reinstalled to correct dependency issues. Just be sure to make a list of impacted packages. This is especially true for VLC  - there were only about 4 or 5 packages impacted the last time I needed to do so.

My preferred repo is RPMForge. http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B

If you have been mixing repositories I highly suggest that you remove all packages from third party repos and start over. This can be done by either an OS reinstall or [manually tracking down the packages](http://fossplanet.com/f11/%5Bcentos%5D-remove-all-packages-specific-repository-53323/). If you did not use yum-priorities to begin with your system is likely very broken and a reinstall would be the best solution.

Comment: now i am using a single repo(RPMFORGE) and i got this problem while installing vlc.........Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libml.so.2.0
Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcvaux.so.2.0
Error: Package: vlc-1.1.11-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libdvdread.so.4
Error: Package: dirac-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.i686 (rpmforge)
etc...

Comment: which is good repository?there is not enough packages in epel.please send me a apropriate repo.